# Java "short" if with multiple "?"

Tags: java

How something like this works:

```
System.out.println(x>20 ? x<0 ? 10:8:7);
```

Or more complicated like:

```
System.out.println(x>20 ? x<10 ? x<2? x==0? 10:8:7:5:8);
```

I understand default usage like this:

```
 System.out.println(z>2?10:8);
```

But "longer" version gives me score that I don't understand why.

Comment: Use brackets to make it more obvious: `System.out.println(x>20 ? (x<0 ? 10:8) : (7) );`. Difficult thing is to find the outermost pairs, remember them, then work your way out from the innermost pair.

Comment: You should really never use more than one conditional operator in the same expression for the very reason you are experiencing here. They are confusing, make it harder to read the code and make it easy to introduce bugs.

Comment: I don't want to use it, i'm learning to my first job interview.

Comment: If someone asks about code like this in a job interview, just say thanks and that you want to end the interview now, because this seems to be a red flag that either their code is hell, or that they care more about trivia than the real world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of this:

```
x>20 ? x<0 ? 10 : 8 : 7
```

As:

```
x>20 ? (x<0 ? 10 : 8) : 7
```

You start with the inner most `?` and `:` pair, group them together, and repeat while working your way outwards.

Written verbosely, it would look like this instead:

```
if (x>20) {
    if (x<0) {
        return 10;
    }
    else {
        return 8;
    }    
}
else {
    return 7;
}
```

Here's the longer one:

```
x>20 ? x<10 ? x<2 ? x==0 ? 10 : 8 : 7 : 5 : 8
```

with grouping:

```
x>20 ? (x<10 ? (x<2 ? (x==0 ? 10 : 8) : 7) : 5) : 8
```

and written verbosely:

```
if (x>20) {
    if (x<10) {
        if (x<2) {
            if (x==2) {
                return 10;
            }
            else {
                return 8;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 7;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 5;
    }
}
else {
    return 8;
}
```